# DataTables JS does not sort date correctly in PHP application

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables, momentjs

I was tasked to fix this table sorting in this PHP app. The table uses [DataTable 1.10](https://datatables.net/) to auto generate the datatable for the php `blade.php` file.

The data coming into the page uses the following format for the "Publish Date":

uploaded_at: "2018-01-02 00:00:00"

`page.blade.php`

```
<table class="table tbl_issue" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid #e9ecef;border-radius: 4px;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Issue Title</th>
                                <th>Publish Date</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @if(count($data['issues']))
                                @foreach($data['issues'] as $issue)
                                @if($issue->uploaded_at >= $data['starts_date'])
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        {{$issue->name}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{date('m/d/Y', strtotime($issue->uploaded_at))}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                @endif
                                @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tbl_issue').DataTable();
});
```

When I click the auto-generated "publish date" filter, the dates are not sorted correctly. (images below)

[image: ASC]
[image: DSC]

As you can see, the `08/18/2016` date is always in the middle.

How can i get this sorting dates correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Datatables API to set that column as type date.

Example:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columns": [
      { "type": "string" },
      { "type": "date" },
  ]
} );
```

See reference:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type

Comment: Datatables SHOULD be able to detect it as a date though from the format you fed the table. You should check to see if there's padding on your date or anything by var_dumping it.